# Map column value to object instance in class hierarchy

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

Let's imagine this class structure:

```
abstract class A {}

class B:A {}
class C:A {}
class D:A {}


class Entity
{
  A PropertyA { get; set; }
}
```

**Entity** is mapped with nhibernate and **PropertyA** is persisted.

My question is: is it possible to store **PropertyA** in database column with some kind of id? For instance:

- if PropertyA  is B then in database store property-b
- if PropertyA  is C then in database store property-c
- if PropertyA  is D then in database store property-d

and also when I query database and Entity is created I would like to have PropertyA initialized to B/C/D, depending on the value in database column. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the answer is **custom types in nHibernate**:

http://blog.miraclespain.com/archive/2008/Mar-18.html